# Select2 v3 > v4 - programmatically set values issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update my JS code to suit v4 (which is used by ACF).

This worked with v3 (where defCountry is a variable set earlier):

```
$('#s2id_acf-field_554f18ecbf60c-input').select2("data", {id: defCountry, text: defCountry});
```

But it doesn't work with v4. I have tried these but to no avail:

```
$('#s2id_acf-field_554f18ecbf60c-input').val( defCountry ); 
$('#s2id_acf-field_554f18ecbf60c-input').val( {id: defCountry, text: defCountry} );
$('#s2id_acf-field_554f18ecbf60c').val( defCountry ); 
$('#s2id_acf-field_554f18ecbf60c').val( {id: defCountry, text: defCountry} );
```

(Both with and without the trigger option.)

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
$('#...').val(defCountry).trigger('change');
```

You should call `.val()` on the same element you did call `.select2(...)`